# Is there any material or documentation about the rabbitmq_prelaunch in rabbitmq-server?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

Is there any material or  documentation  about the rabbitmq_prelaunch in rabbitmq-server?

```
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/tree/main/deps/rabbit/apps/rabbitmq_prelaunch
```

Comment: No, just the code itself.

Comment: Thank you ,I see. I am reading the code.